# Laravel 4 Artisan & Guzzle - Causing zombie processes

Tags: php, laravel, centos

For an in-office site checking statusboard, i'm using L4, and an artisan command that uses Guzzle to send http requests to a list of sites.

For some reason, if left long enough, coming back to the server and running `top`, shows that there are up to a dozen `php artisan check:sites` processes still running, causing memory issues on the server, and other processes to fail due to out of memory errors.

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this? I thought it might have perhaps been Guzzle / php-curl leaking memory, but i would love to know if there's a way to stop it doing this.

Just as a side note - the php command executed by cron is actually setting a timeout of 120 seconds, using the `-d max_execution_time=120` flag, thinking this might kill any processes completely after two minutes, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with some commands, which get and parse some RSS feeds. I'd love some help on this :/

Answer (score 0):

You could check the timeout for Guzzle requests and set it to less than 10 seconds

```
$request = $client->get('http://test.com', [], ['timeout' => 10]);
```